# Conditional if else if returning values for incorrect match

Tags: google-apps-script

I am currently trying to use a form that you can choose a name and based on that choice it returns values from a separate spreadsheet.  The problem is the if and else if are giving me weird results.  The first 3 work fine but the 4th returns the values for the first if (jillian) and cali returns the values for ashley.  I have looked for an open bracket or anything that would point me in the right direction with no luck.  Below is the script I am using.

```
function emailInfoRequired() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Form Responses 1");
  var data = sheet.getRange(sheet.getLastRow(), 1, 1,       sheet.getLastColumn()).getValues();
var player = data[0][1].trim();
var email = data[0][2].trim();
 var jillianachoice = /^[Jillian A].*$/i;
 var trinitybchoice = /^[Trinity B].*$/i;
 var emmabchoice = /^[Emma B].*$/i;
 var ashleycchoice = /^[Ashley C].*$/i;
 var caliechoice = /^[Cali E].*$/i;
 var chloehchoice = /^[Chloe H].*$/i;
 var sierrajchoice = /^[Sierra J].*$/i;
 var kirakchoice = /^[Kira K].*$/i;
 var skylarkchoice = /^[Skylar K].*$/i;
 var alainalchoice = /^[Alaina L].*$/i;
 var jadynnchoice = /^[Jadyn N].*$/i;
 var kaedingrchoice = /^[Kaeding R].*$/i;
 var schuylerrchoice = /^[Schuyler R].*$/i;
 var taylorschoice = /^[Taylor S].*$/i;
 var bellaschoice = /^[Bella S].*$/i;
 var elizabethschoice = /^[Elizabeth S].*$/i;
 var abbywchoice = /^[Abby W].*$/i;

 var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById("spreadsheetID");//other spreadsheet with the values 
 var sheet1 = ss.getSheetByName("Form Responses 1");
 var subject = "U13G Neon Player Stats Averages";
 var recipients = email;
 var Header = sheet1.getRange('C1:F1').getValues();
 var jilliana = sheet1.getRange('C2:F2').getValues();// define your range here
 var trinityb = sheet1.getRange('C3:F3').getValues();// define your range here
 var emmab = sheet1.getRange('C4:F4').getValues();// define your range here
 var ashleyc = sheet1.getRange('C5:F5').getValues();// define your range here
 var calie = sheet1.getRange('C6:F6').getValues();// define your range here
 var chloeh = sheet1.getRange('C7:F7').getValues();// define your range here
 var sierraj = sheet1.getRange('C8:F8').getValues();// define your range here
 var kirak = sheet1.getRange('C9:F9').getValues();// define your range here
 var skylark = sheet1.getRange('C10:F10').getValues();// define your range here
 var alainal = sheet1.getRange('C11:F11').getValues();// define your range here
 var jadynn = sheet1.getRange('C12:F12').getValues();// define your range here
 var kaedingr = sheet1.getRange('C13:F13').getValues();// define your range here
 var schuylerr = sheet1.getRange('C14:F14').getValues();// define your range here
 var taylors = sheet1.getRange('C15:F15').getValues();// define your range here
 var bellas = sheet1.getRange('C16:F16').getValues();// define your range here
 var elizabeths = sheet1.getRange('C17:F17').getValues();// define your range here
 var abbyw = sheet1.getRange('C18:F18').getValues();// define your range here
 if (jillianachoice(player)) {
    var message = '<HTML><BODY><p>Jillian A</p><table style="border-collapse:collapse;" border = 1><tr>';// change eventually the color here

 for (var row1 = 0;row1<Header.length;++row1){
 for(var col1 = 0;col1<Header[0].length;++col1){


  message += '<th style="height:100%; width:5%">'+Header[row1][col1]+'</th>'; 
 }
 message += '</tr><tr>';
 }
    for (var row2 = 0;row2<jilliana.length;++row2){
 for(var col2 = 0;col2<jilliana[0].length;++col2){
 message += '<th style="height:100%; width:5%">'+jilliana[row2][col2]+'</th>';
 }
 }
 message += '</tr></table></body></HTML>';

 MailApp.sendEmail(recipients, subject, "", {htmlBody: message});
 } else if (trinitybchoice(player)) {
    var message1 = '<HTML><BODY><p>Trinity B</p><table style="border-collapse:collapse;" border = 1><tr>';// change eventually the color here

 for (var row3 = 0;row3<Header.length;++row3){
 for(var col3 = 0;col3<Header[0].length;++col3){


  message1 += '<th style="height:100%; width:5%">'+Header[row3][col3]+'</th>'; 
  }
  message1 += '</tr><tr>';
  }
    for (var row4 = 0;row4<trinityb.length;++row4){
    for(var col4 = 0;col4<trinityb[0].length;++col4){
  message1 += '<th style="height:100%; width:5%">'+trinityb[row4][col4]+'</th>';
  }
 }
 message1 += '</tr></table></body></HTML>';

 MailApp.sendEmail(recipients, subject, "", {htmlBody: message1});
} else if (emmabchoice(player)) {
    var message2 = '<HTML><BODY><p>Emma B</p><table style="border-collapse:collapse;" border = 1><tr>';// change eventually the color here

 for (var row5 = 0;row5<Header.length;++row5){
 for(var col5 = 0;col5<Header[0].length;++col5){


  message2 += '<th style="height:100%; width:5%">'+Header[row5][col5]+'</th>'; 
 }
 message2 += '</tr><tr>';
 }
    for (var row6 = 0;row6<emmab.length;++row6){
 for(var col6 = 0;col6<emmab[0].length;++col6){
 message2 += '<th style="height:100%; width:5%">'+emmab[row6][col6]+'</th>';
 }
 }
 message2 += '</tr></table></body></HTML>';

 MailApp.sendEmail(recipients, subject, "", {htmlBody: message2});
} else if (ashleycchoice(player)) {
    var message3 = '<HTML><BODY><p>Ashley C</p><table style="border-collapse:collapse;" border = 1><tr>';// change eventually the color here

 for(var row7 = 0;row7<Header.length;++row7){
 for(var col7 = 0;col7<Header[0].length;++col7){


  message3 += '<th style="height:100%; width:5%">'+Header[row7][col7]+'</th>'; 
 }
 message3 += '</tr><tr>';
 }
    for(var row8 = 1;row8<ashleyc.length;++row8){
 for(var col8 = 1;col8<ashleyc[0].length;++col8){
 message3 += '<th style="height:100%; width:5%">'+ashleyc[row8][col8]+'</th>';
 }
}
 message3 += '</tr></table></body></HTML>';

 MailApp.sendEmail(recipients, subject, "", {htmlBody: message3});
} else if (caliechoice(player)) {
    var message4 = '<HTML><BODY><p>Cali E</p><table style="border-collapse:collapse;" border = 1><tr>';// change eventually the color here

 for (var row9 = 0;row9<Header.length;++row9){
 for(var col9 = 0;col9<Header[0].length;++col9){


  message4 += '<th style="height:100%; width:5%">'+Header[row9][col9]+'</th>'; 
 }
 message4 += '</tr><tr>';
 }
    for (var row10 = 0;row10<calie.length;++row10){
 for(var col10 = 0;col10<calie[0].length;++col10){
 message4 += '<th style="height:100%; width:5%">'+calie[row10][col10]+'</th>';
 }
}
 message4 += '</tr></table></body></HTML>';

 MailApp.sendEmail(recipients, subject, "", {htmlBody: message4}); //Plus 12 more players
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK.. I found the problem.  Since the variable uses a regular expression such as:

```
var jillianachoice = /^[Jillian A].*$/i;
```

The .* is telling it to match anything in the brackets and the i is telling it to ignore case.  What is supposed to be there for what I was trying to accomplish is:

```
var jillianachoice = /^Jillian A$/;
```

This will take the literal instead of matching any of the letters.